# Why can't my Core 1 library be seen in my ASP.NET Core 1.0 (MVC6) project?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a little class library (Core 1), separate so that other apps may also use it, and all those reasons. It has only POCO model classes and a `DbContext` derivative. Its project file looks as follows:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
        "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.5": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have an *ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)* that I wish to use the class library in. Nearly everywhere I look, and I've looked, says to just add the library to the main project's `dependencies` section of its project file. There it is, right at the top:

```
"dependencies": {
    "WideWorld.Filing": "1.0.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
        "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

I can't even see the library namespace `WideWorld.Filing` in the main project, where I can, obviously, see its namespace, `WideWorld.Office`. I am very, very new to Core 1, and have only build monolith web applications before, so please excuse my ignorance if I'm missing something obvious.

If I do a package restore on the main project, I get three warnings in the log (and other stuff that looks harmless):

```
warn : Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from 1.0.0 to 1.0.0-rc2-final 
warn :  WideWorld.Office (>= 1.0.0) -> WideWorld.Filing (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 1.0.0) 
warn :  WideWorld.Office (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 1.0.0-rc2-final)
```

Comment: There is no MVC6 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/

Comment: Also don't use the RC versions of the tooling/SDK, it's been released for almost 2 months https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/announcing-net-core-1-0/

Comment: Tseng, I am well aware of that, but the names have only recently changed, and a great many people know it as MVC 6, and I would rather have reach than perfection. Anyhow, I've updated it.

Comment: "Recently"? The change has been first announced in January and were officially reflected with RC2 which is 3 months old. This is to avoid confusion about the frameworks, as MVC6 sounds like its compatible with the old MVC1-5 line of frameworks, which it isn't. The official name of it is "ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0" which is reflected in it's package name: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc : 1.0.0`, on top of that, DNX is unsupported and deprecated since RC2. dotnet-cli is the only supported way for .NET Core applications now

Comment: As for the question, are they in the same solution? And in the same folder listed in the folder specified in the global.json's `projects` property?

Comment: Yes, they are both in the `src` folder of the same solution, and there is only one `src` listed in `project.json'.

Comment: Any errors during package restore? (Output View => Show output from "Package Manager")

Comment: Only three warnings. I have added them to the question.

Comment: Are they both targeting the same framework? Are all dependencies up to date?

Comment: @Slicc They were not, but are now, yet I still have the same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't mix package versions, very bad. Your EntityFrameworkCore package is from RTM (version 1.0.0) where rest of your project is RC2. I'd fist suggest to have all target the same version of .NET Core (1.0.0) and upgrade your RC2 project to RTM. RTM for example uses `netstandard1.6` moniker

Comment: And how do I his change? Please answer this last question properly, as answer, not just a comment, then I can accept it.

Comment: did you add the project as a reference in your main project?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich In 'project.json', yes. The old fasioned ticking a file out o f a long list is fast becoming history in Core 1. And it isn't available to add as a reference the old way.

Comment: @ProfK only a few moments remaining to award the bounty. I believe I have the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're mixing packages versions. For example the `RTM` and `RC2` packages are not compatible. You should either target everything as `RC2` (which I'd advise against) or take the more preferred approach and upgrade all package references to `RTM`, targeting version `1.0.0`.

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library):

Note, I have omitted the `"import": "dnxcore50"`

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.5": { }
    }
}
```

Likewise, in the other `project.json` do this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "WideWorld.Filing": "1.0.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0"
```

Additional details on [packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages).

Comment: Only one answer, and a good one. I haven't been able to test it yet, but from what I know it makes good sense.